# Date Picker not working

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I tried to add and delete row with date picker in the table. By default the date picker has not working. But I clicked the add row button, it has worked. I couldn't find the solution.

Please refer the Fiddle location.

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/MJGV2/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datepicker not working on first time beacause you not intilized datepicker at fist time

here is new fiddle ..http://jsfiddle.net/MJGV2/2/

```
// intilize datepicker at document ready or load..
$(document).ready(function(){

        setdatepicker();

});

$("input[type='button'].AddRow").live('click',
function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    if (index > 0) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    } else {


        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
        var $input = $tr.find('input.startdatum');
        var index = $('input#counter').val();
         $('#test').val('Delete');
        var id = 'datepicker' + index;
        index++;

        $('input#counter').val(index);
        $input.attr('id', id).data('index', index);
        console.log(index);
        $tr.prependTo($(this).closest('table'));
      setdatepicker();

    }

});


function setdatepicker(){

  $('.startdatum').each(function() {
            $(this).datepicker('destroy');
            $(this).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must enable datepicker on DOMready,

You can do something like this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MJGV2/5/)

```
 $("input[type='button'].AddRow").live('click',
 function() {
var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
if (index > 0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();

} else {


    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
    var $input = $tr.find('input.startdatum');
    var index = $('input#counter').val();
     $('#test').val('Delete');
    var id = 'datepicker' + index;
    index++;

    $('input#counter').val(index);
    $input.attr('id', id).data('index', index);
    console.log(index);
    $tr.prependTo($(this).closest('table'));
    enable_dp();

}

 });
enable_dp();
function enable_dp()
 {

  $('.startdatum').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker('destroy');
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
        });
    });
 }
```